# Copy file from remote to local using ssh

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, terminal, scp

I'm trying to copy a file from a Ubuntu server to my mac but I keep receiving a No such file or directory error.

After I ssh in I'm using:

```
scp -p 8888 me@xx1.xx1.xx1.xx1:/var/www/html/00000001.jpg /Users/myusername/Documents/
```

But receive the error:

```
/Users/myusername/Documents/: No such file or directory
```

Is this error telling me that there is no such file or directory on my local machine? Any advice as to how to fix would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't ssh in to your server first. Just execute that scp command from your local machine.

EDIT:

Also, the `-p` should be capitalized (according to the manpage on my machine), so:

```
scp -P 8888 your_username@remotehost.edu:/var/www/html/00000001.jpg /Users/myusername/Documents/
```

Comment: best advice "Don't ssh in to your server first. " tks !
Explaining: if you do that, rcp will need to know about your local host at the command parameters

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's talking about your local machine. I'm guessing that you might have just typed something wrong. Try doing it like this instead:

```
scp -P 8888 me@xx1.xx1.xx1.xx1:/var/www/html/00000001.jpg ~/Documents/
```

Make sure you're typing this command at your Mac OS X Terminal prompt, not on the actual remote server. `xx1.xx1.xx1.xx1` should be the remote Ubuntu machine ("pull" the file down to your machine, don't try to "push" it).

Also, although it's `ssh -p`, it's `scp -P`. For `scp`, `-p` just preserves modification times, and `-P` is the port.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have multiple ssh connections open.

Try close all other connections and restart the scp command.